# VS Code terminal doesn't execute commands

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, cmd, terminal

every time I try to execute a command, the message below appears. I just installed Node, npm, React by Windows terminal, but VS Code doesn't recognize any command.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjrF0.png)

**The term '' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException**

Comment: That's a PowerShell, not VS Code, error. PowerShell is the default terminal in VS Code. Check that both node and npm are on the path environment variable - they probably aren't by default but depends how you install node.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a VSCode error. You only need to close the VSCode terminal  (the trashbin button) and create a new one. Usually happens when you install Node with the VSCode terminal open.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I installed Node a long time on my other notebook and I couldn't remember why it wasn't working. 

Comment: No problem. If you have any other questions don't hesitate to ask on StackOverflow :p

Answer (score 0):

@phuzi Also will meet this problem when install `System Installer` version of VSCode and didn't run as Admin. So it's not completely unrelated to VSCode.

**this problem**: Only in VSCode Terminal(PowerShell) `xxx is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`, but ok in others such as `Windows PowerShell(actually contains terminal and shell)` and `Windows Terminal with PowerShell`

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have just downloaded node.js and opened vs code before downloading it. You just need to close vs code and reopen it, it should be fine.